# Dart: Convert String representation of List of Lists to List of List

Tags: dart

this is the same question as here:

[How can I convert this string to list of lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2644221/how-can-i-convert-this-string-to-list-of-lists)

but for Dart rather than python. My aim (as in the other question) is to take a string like:

```
String stringRep = '[[123],[122],[411]]';
```

And convert it to a List of lists. I can see I would be able to achieve this using one of the methods recommended in answer referenced above, namely:

```
str = "[[0,0,0],[0,0,1],[1,1,0]]"
strs = str.replace('[','').split('],')
lists = [map(int, s.replace(']','').split(',')) for s in strs]
```

But wondering if there is a better method in Dart but struggling to fnd any online?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use the JSON decoder

```
import 'dart:convert';

...

var lists = json.decode('[[123],[122],[411]]');
```

[**DartPad example**](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/ada0a1860a5f0cc694915afe1e75d899)

**update**

```
final regExp = new RegExp(r'(?:\[)?(\[[^\]]*?\](?:,?))(?:\])?');
final input = '[[sometext],[122],[411]]';
final result = regExp.allMatches(input).map((m) => m.group(1))
  .map((String item) => item.replaceAll(new RegExp(r'[\[\],]'), ''))
  .map((m) => [m])
  .toList();
print(result);
```

[**DartPad example**](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/d77889ea688bfa41e85c03221667e25d)

Comment: Ah, this is exactly what I was trying. I see now though that the problem I had was I was converting text that was entered from a GUI. If you try:

var lists = JSON.decode('[[sometext],[122],[411]]');

Then you get an error which must be the problem I was having.

Comment: That's because `sometext'` would require quotes to be valid JSON, but your question didn't contain text, only numbers ;-)

Comment: Hey thanks so much! Sorry to ignore last answer - was busy failing to get to that same solution!

Comment: I believe it is now json.decode(), instead of JSON.decode().

Comment: Thanks. And what if it were `"['[123]','[122]','[411]']"` ?

Comment: Looks like you want to `json.decode()` every element of the array returned by the first `json.decode()`