# Convert the string inside of the list into list format (Flutter)

Tags: string, flutter, list

How to regenerate whole list to convert string(list) inside of the list into list format

```
 List<Map<String, dynamic>> category = [
    {
      "name": "One",
      "detail": "['1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1']"
    },
    {
      "name": "two",
      "detail": "['2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2']"
    },
    {
      "name": "three",
      "detail": "['3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3']"
    },
  ];


Become

 List<Map<String, dynamic>> category = [
    {
      "name": "One",
      "detail": ['1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1']
    },
    {
      "name": "two",
      "detail": ['2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2']
    },
    {
      "name": "three",
      "detail": ['3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3']
    },
  ];
```

How to regenerate whole list to convert string(list) inside of the list into list format

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dart: Convert String representation of List of Lists to List of List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43810508/dart-convert-string-representation-of-list-of-lists-to-list-of-list)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
List<Map<String, dynamic>> category = [
    {
      "name": "One",
      "detail": "['1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1']"
    },
    {
      "name": "two",
      "detail": "['2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2']"
    },
    {
      "name": "three",
      "detail": "['3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3']"
    },
  ];


for(var e in category){
    Map<String,dynamic> item = e;
    String s = e['detail'];
    s = s.substring(1,s.length-1);
    item['detail'] = s.split(',');
    result.add(item);
  }

print(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

**There are more ways of doing this :**

try running this example on [dartpad](https://dartpad.dev/)

```
import 'dart:convert';

void main() {
  String ss = "['3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3']";
  String a= ss.replaceAll('[','');
  String b= a.replaceAll(']','');
  String c= b.replaceAll("'",'');
  List result = c.split(',');
  print(result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (var element in category) {
  element['detail'] = json.decode(element['detail'].toString().replaceAll("\'", "\""));
}
log("$category");
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Comment: [A code-only answer is not high quality](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers). While this code may be useful, you can improve it by saying why it works, how it works, when it should be used, and what its limitations are. Please [edit] your answer to include explanation and link to relevant documentation.