# Python program for writing length of list to file

Tags: python

I have a file `list.txt` that contains a single list only e.g.

```
[asd,ask,asp,asq]
```

The list might be a very long one. I want to create a python program `len.py` that reads `list.txt` and writes the length of the within list to the file `num.txt`. Something like the following:

```
fin = open("list.txt", "rt")
fout = open("num.txt", "wt")

for list in fin:
    fout.write(len(list))

fin.close()
fout.close()
```

However this does not work. Can someone point out what needs to be changed? Many thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Have you read through the [documentation for the `open()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open)? `open()` returns a `File` object and isn't capable of *interpreting* the contents of the file on its own.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert string representation of list to list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894269/convert-string-representation-of-list-to-list)

Comment: @esqew Thanks. I don't think that answers it, but then I'm not familiar at all with python. The input file I'm using comes from another application and just I need a way of reading its length. I will have a look at the documentation referenced.

Comment: you should consider making list.txt a json file so your text in the file would be `["'asd", "ask", "asp", "asq"]` then you can load it an an actual python list and see the length of it with the `len()` function. Also, I wouldnt name your module `len.py` because `len` is a built in python function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with open("list.txt") as fin, open("num.txt", "w") as fout:
    input_data = fin.readline()
    # check if there was any info read from input file
    if input_data:
        # split string into list on comma character
        strs = input_data.replace('[','').split('],')
        lists = [map(int, s.replace(']','').split(',')) for s in strs]
        print(len(lists))
        fout.write(str(len(lists)))
```

I updated the code to use the with statement from another answer. I also used some code from this answer ([How can I convert this string to list of lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2644221/how-can-i-convert-this-string-to-list-of-lists)) to (more?) correctly count nested lists.

Comment: Many thanks. I'm getting an error on line 10 when I run this: `fout.write(len(output_list))
TypeError: expected a character buffer object`

Comment: I updated the code to avoid that issue. the len() function returns an integer, but write() expects a string. It should run without error now.

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
with open("list.txt") as f1, open("num.txt", "w") as f2:
    for line in f1:
        line = line.strip('\n[]')
        f2.write(str(len(line.split(','))) + '\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

When python try to read a file using default method it generally treats content of that file as a string. So first responsibility is to type cast string content into appropriate content type for that you can not use default type casting method.

You can use special package by the name **ast** to type cast the data.

```
import ast

fin = open("list.txt", "r")
fout = open("num.txt", "w")

for list in fin.readlines():
    fout.write(len(ast.literal_eval(list)))

fin.close()
fout.close()
```